# How can I make these blurry Shape?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, transform, blur, distort

I tried to create these shapes several times ago without success. I tried with illustrator and a blurry shape that I deform with "Envelope Distort" > "make with mesh" but the result isn't very convincing. I'd tried with photoshop but there isn't a tool like the one in illustrator…

Can you help me ?

1st image :
[image]

2nd image (bonus): 
[image]

Bonus : can you help me too, to make the effect of the second image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first image, I'd recommend looking at the liquify filter

As for the second, there's a lot of ways to achieve something like that. It certainly doesn't look like one sort of effect. For example, creating a shape with no fill, add a gradient effect. Turn it into a smart object, add gaussian blur and noise and you'll get something like this:

[image]

Adding a few layers like this and playing with the blending would get to something like what you're after.

Comment: I'm feeling stupid to haven't tried this before. I'll try the 2nd tip later but your explications seems good. Thanks again.